# Cannot change inet address to anything eth0

Tags: debian, networking

For some reason, I cannot change the inet address of `eth0` to anything else than `10.0.0.9`. When I do so through the command: `sudo ifconfig eth0 inet 10.0.0.X`, pages, pings, etc. load for 30 seconds and then say **Unknown Host** or **Webpage not found**. What could be the issue to this?

My Ethernet PCI is `BCM57765`, and I installed the corresponding driver (tg3).

`lsmod | grep tg3`

```
tg3                   164481  0 
ptp                    17692  1 tg3
libphy                 32268  1 tg3
```

In the network manager,I tried adding:

```
[eth0]
managed=false
```

However it did not do anything. My `/etc/network/interfaces` is default, except of the `auto eth0` line. I previously tried `iface eth0 inet static` to set static IP as a workaround, but that did not work either.

```
iface eth0 inet static
       address 10.0.0.7
       gateway 10.0.0.138
       netmask 255.0.0.0
```

Comment: You have dhcpcd and no matter the ip address is defined as static, the daemon asks for an IP to dhcp. if you have a static address, you should stop it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I stopped the static config. However, that was on 10.0.0.7, and I cant change to anything else than 10.0.0.9. Static though didnt change to the ip defined either

Comment: Tell me the distribution to complete the answer please.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Debian 8 (Jessie). Is networkmanager also related to the problem?

Comment: could be, if using static addresses, stop it.

Comment: (Debian 8 here too, but I do not use either systemd or networkmanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dhcpcd running and no matter the ip address is defined as static, the daemon asks for an IP to dhcp. if you have a static address, you should stop it.

Otherwise, any time you change the status of the interface changing the IP, it just does a DHCP request, and is back again to the DHCP-given IP.

Do a service dhcpcd stop and try it.

If you wish to keep using fixed ip addresses, run:

```
 $sudo service dhcpcd stop
 $sudo aptitude install chkconfig
 $sudo chkconfig dhcpcd off
```

Comment: Did that, disabled static, and reloaded network-manager from init.d. and dhcpd says that it is not found, but it _did_ work after all

Comment: It is not dhcpd but dhcpcd. Glad it worked.

Comment: dhcpcd does not work either. But that does not matter as the problem is resolved